# Detect one tap and long tap on touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement two touch functions. One tap and long tap. I have implemented one tap which is pretty straightforward but for a long tap function, a timer must be set?

I would like the long press to be active only after 1 second of holding the tap and then the timer should get reset on release. How do I do this?

```
public float longTapTime;

void Update()
{
   if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)) {
    //One tap
  }

  if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
  {
     longTapTime = 0;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float long_tap_consider_duration = 1.0f;

    private float time_helper;
    private float duration;
    private bool is_touched;
    private void Start()
    {
        time_helper = 0;
        duration = 0;
        is_touched = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            ProcessInput();
    }
    private void ProcessInput()
    {
        if (is_touched && ((Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) || (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)))
        {
            if (duration > long_tap_consider_duration)
                OnLongTap();
            else OnTap();
        }

        if (!is_touched && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
        {
            time_helper = Time.time;
            is_touched = true;
        }
        duration = Time.time - time_helper;
    }

    //Callback function, when just a short tap occurs
    private void OnTap()
    {
        Debug.Log("Short Tap");
    }
    //Callback function, when long tap occurs
    private void OnLongTap()
    {
        Debug.Log("Long Tap");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to handle multiple touches to detect whether it is a short tap or long tap you can use a very useful asset called Layered Based Touch Manager/System. Here is the link to that asset demo: https://youtu.be/-GwgMdiZGrU

Answer (score 1):

actually, if you are using the new input system, this is a built in feature and does not need any code.

1. find your  Input Actions  ".inputActions"
2. find the button on the list of inputs registered
3. with that item selected, find the plus "+" next to the word interactions on the right hand side
4. add a "hold" interaction from the list and set desired hold time.

for more information on the input action asset system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvuXOyKz7k4