# Detecting difference in single tap and long tap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have implemented single tap and long tap functions. The long tap gets activated if the tap is held for 0.5 seconds and function gets executed only if the touch is released. How do I avoid this?

Such that the long tap function should get activated when the touch is pressed and held for 0.5 seconds instead of releasing the touch?

```
private float TouchTime = 0;

 void Update () {

        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            TouchTime = Time.time;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) {
            if (Time.time - TouchTime <= 0.5) {
            //Single Tap
           } else {
            //Long Tap
           }
}
```

Comment: Are you using new input system? I thought it should be done easier like [there](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Interactions.html)

Comment: wasn't just the same thing [asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68059208/detect-one-tap-and-long-tap-on-touch) ?

Comment: @derHugo I tried that solution but for me the problem is quite different. Both single and double tap work for me. The only issue is the double tap gets activated only if the touch is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the touch to end you could do e.g.

```
pubic float longPressTime = 0.5f;

bool alreadyFiredLongPress;
float timeElapsed;

void Update () 
{
    // First of all this is how you get the touches!
    // Check if any touch even exists
    // and then do not go through Input.touches which is very expensive!
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began: 
                // Start/Reset the timer
                timeElapsed = 0;
                alreadyFiredLongPress = false;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Stationary:
                // Only fire the long press once
                if(!alreadyFiredLongPress)
                {
                    // increase by the time passed since last frame
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                    // pressed long enough?
                    if(timeElapsed >= longPressTime)
                    {
                        // block the single tap and other long press events
                        alreadyFiredLongPress = true;
                        // Long Tap
                    }
                }
                break;

            // in all other cases
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
            case TouchPhase.Canceled:
                // Fire single tap if no long tap was trigdered before
                if(!alreadyFiredLongPress)
                {
                    //Single Tap
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is hopefully simpler

```
private float TouchTime = 0;
private float _longTouchThreshold = 0.5f; // minimum time in seconds for long touch
private bool _isTouching = false;

void Update () 
{
    Touch touch = Input.touches[0];

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        TouchTime = Time.time;
        _isTouching = true;
    }

    // touch has started
    if (_isTouching)
    {
        // minimum time has passed for long touch
        if (Time.time - TouchTime >= _longTouchThreshold) {
            _isTouching = false;
            // long touch
        }
        // minimum time hasn't passed but touch ended
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) {
            _isTouching = false;
            // single tap
        }
    }
}
```